# How to merge reduce outputs and use in map input?

Tags: java, file, hadoop

I am writting a program in hadoop. my code has two stages . in stage 1 , i have 6 reduce output file and this files are the input in the next stage. in stage 2 , i want to have 2 maps so i must merge 6 outputs of stage 1. I have used `copymerg` , but i got `EOFException`. the way i used this function is:

```
copyMerge(FileSystem srcFS, Path srcDir, FileSystem dstFS, Path dstFile, boolean deleteSource, Configuration conf, String addString)
```

I don't know what is `addString`. i have used `""` instead of that.Is it correct?
in this case my map task fails. the task log is:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:180)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer$Buffer.write(DataOutputBuffer.java:63)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer.write(DataOutputBuffer.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.next(SequenceFile.java:1930)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.next(SequenceFile.java:2062)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:68)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:531)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext.nextKeyValue(MapContext.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:369)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:259)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:253)
```

Is this way correct?
Does the `copyMerge` function use ram to copy the file? means that if the the file be 1 gigabyte, i need 1 G ram to copy it?
Thanks.